# open file in new tab without creating local or server copy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, crystal-reports

I have program which stores crystal reports (in bytes in database) and then gives a list of them to user (MVC5). When user clicks on report's name in the list he should see the report in pdf in new tab. On server side I get data contains binary data and length from db. The question is - how to open this data in new tab and not to download converted file on server or local machine?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve opening a pdf in new browser tab by using window.open and call your server side method in jquery something like this..

jQuery:

```
$('.reportName').click(function () {
 window.open("../../ControllerName/ActionMethodName, '_blank');
});
```

Server Side:

```
public static void ActionMethodName()
{

///Here you got to convert your crystal report to memory stream inorder to pass stream array data inside binary write///

HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline;  filename=*****.pdf");
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Expires = -1;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(outStream.ToArray());
}
```